# Derived completeness and condensed mathematics

Tags: condensed-mathematics

This is a vague question: Does condensed mathematics have something to do with the notion of derived completeness?

Namely, for a ring $R$ and an ideal $I$, one can speak about the category of derived $I$-complete complexes of $R$-modules. On the other hand, I've heard that condensed mathematics has something to do with the notion of "complete modules". So, my very naive question is "Does condensed math give a better approach to the above category?"

I'm sorry for the vagueness of my question, but any information would be appreciated.

Comment: They are related. For example, the collection of *connective* derived $T$-complete objects in the derived category of solid $\mathbb Z[T]$-modules is stable under the (solid) tensor product, thus the solid tensor product coincides with the $T$-completed tensor product when the solid $\mathbb Z[T]$-modules come from derived $T$-completions of discrete $\mathbb Z[T]$-modules.

Comment: @Z.M Thanks for the comment! Well, you mean that the monoidal category of solid $\mathbb{Z}[T]$-modules contains the monoidal subcategory of derived $T$-complete $\mathbb{Z}[T]$-modules. How are they different? Is the former one very bigger than the latter?

Comment: There are three categories (and all modules are derived): the category of solid $\mathbb Z[T]$-modules, the category of derived $T$-complete solid $\mathbb Z[T]$-modules, and the category of derived $T$-complete "discrete" $\mathbb Z[T]$-modules. Each former contains and is strictly larger than its later, and the last is embedding in the second via the $T$-completion functor (not the naive inclusion — this is expected, since derived complete modules should be endowed with "$T$-adic topology"). A more precise form: the embedding of the second in the first is symmetric monoidal on connectives.

Comment: @Z.M Thanks for the clarification! Are the objects of the former two categories which are not contained in the classical third one something pathological? (since they do not appear in the classical (non-condensed)math...)

Comment: Not at all. These objects do exist in classical (analytic) geometry, and condensed mathematics is a well-behaved framework to incorporate those objects, well-behaved in the sense that there is a good theory of homological algebra.

Comment: @Z.M Great, thanks! Now I'm motivated to look in their lecture note!